# how do I detect a data connection?

Tags: sensors, power, data

on an ardunio, is there a way to detect if a data connection (vs power only) is present? I want to have my arduino behave differently if connected to a pc, or on stand alone power.

specifically, I have a project that sends keystrokes to a midi piano program I wrote, but when a pc is not connected, I would like to have the arduino send the notes to a peizo buzzer attached to the circuit instead. 
Im using a teensy, or a leonardo, or an Uno.

Comment: You could have the main code run when a signal is sent over the serial monitor...

Comment: Teensy and Leonardo, probably yes. Uno - no.

Comment: for sending keystrokes, no on the uno, but I still think it may be possible to get a status indication. useful for other projects. does the arduino look at the rx/tx pins of the usb?

Comment: Are you using the `Keyboard` class to send HID reports, or are you using `Serial` and then your program is interpreting it as key presses?

Comment: In this project I am using the keyboard class. I was thinking the arduino would have a data pin I could monitor.